# Printing all the elements in 1 index of a hash table?

Tags: c++

This is my HashTable class definition

```
class HashTable {
public:
    /**Constructors*/

    HashTable(){}
    //constructor

    ~HashTable(){}
    //destructor


    /**Access Functions*/

    int hash(string key) const;

    int countBucket(int index) const;

    int search(Book b) const;

    /**Manipulation Procedures*/

    void insert(Book b);

    void remove(Book b);

    void printBucket(ostream& out, int index) const;

    void printTable(ostream& out) const;

private:
    static const int SIZE = 10;
    List<Book> Table[SIZE];
};
```

This is the class definition for List

```
template <class listdata>
class List {

private:
    struct Node {
        listdata data;
        Node* next;
        Node* previous;

        Node(listdata newData){
            data = newData;
            next = NULL;
            previous = NULL;
        }
    };

    Node* start;
    Node* stop;
    Node* iterator;
    int length;


public:
    List();
    List(const List<listdata>& list);
    ~List();

    listdata getStart() const;
    listdata getStop() const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
    int getLength() const;
    listdata getIterator() const;
    bool offEnd() const;
    bool operator==(const List& list) const;
    int getIndex() const;

    void removeStart();
    void removeStop();
    void insertStart (listdata data);
    void insertStop(listdata data);
    void startIterator();
    void removeIterator();
    void insertIterator(listdata data);
    void moveIterNext();
    void moveIterPrevious();
    void moveToIndex(int index);

    void displayList(ostream& out) const;

};
```

I have no idea how to print out all the elements of a specific index in the hashtable using printBucket(). I think I would need to traverse through the list and print each element that way, but I don't know how I can use any of the list functions to do that. I thought about using the iterator functions, but that doesn't work since printBucket() is a constant member function, so I can't use things like startIterator().

Comment: Without the full code is hard to say, but why can't you just iterate up to `countBucket()` and use `printBucket()`?

Comment: In addition, I am unsure what you mean by using the functions from `List` -- you don't have access to those from the `HashTable` anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I just have to say that this design is rigid and grim, and exactly the reason `std::list` exists (I assume this isn't yours, just warn against taking design tips from this). Anyway, if you just want to traverse the list you can do something like `Table[index].moveToIndex( 0 ); for ( int i = 0; i < Table[index].getLength( ); ++i ) { /*do print stuff*/ if ( i < Table[index].getLength( ) - 1 )  moveIterNext(); } Table[index].moveToIndex( 0 );`